# Cómo que le tumbaron con ese perro? - meaning of "tumbar"

Tags: definiciones

I have heard the following sentence in Narcos (a TV series which takes place in Colombia):

> Cómo que le tumbaron con ese perro?

Context: Pablo Escobar bets with his partner Gacha that Gacha's drug-sniffing dog wouldn't be able to detect the cocaine mixed with the glass fiber in a hull of a boat. When the dog indeed doesn't detect the cocaine, Pablo says the line above.

What does "tumbar" mean in this context? The meanings of "tumbar" I see in the Word Reference dictionary are "to knock down", "to incline".

Comment: "Tumbar" seems to also mean "engañar" (deceive/scam) in Colombia ([source](https://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Tumbar.php)). The sentence might mean that whoever gave that dog to Gacha has lied about how good the dog was. But I am not from Colombia so I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Colombia, "tumbar" can mean "enganãr" (to deceive/scam). This is the meaning of the verb in the given sentence. Pablo suggests that whoever gave/sold that dog to Gacha or whoever trained it has lied about how good the dog was.

References:

- http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tumbar
- https://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Tumbar.php